# Java: Switch inside do while loop

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while, break

I tried  to make a multiple random pick ups that would print the message for each input number, i.e. serie of numbers (4 2 17 0) where 0 will stop the code. Got wrong output

````
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int number=scanner.nextInt();
       
  int x = number;
do{switch(x) {

case 1:
      System.out.println("Language selection");
break;
case 2:
       System.out.println("Customer support");
break;
case 3:
       System.out.println("Check the balance");
break;

case 4:
       System.out.println("Check loan balance");
break;
case 0:
System.out.println("Exit");
break;
  
default:
return;

}
if (x==0)
{break;}
x++;
}

while (true);

   }
} ```
![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJBYn.jpg)

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCm4p.jpg)
````

Comment: You need a `break` in every case statement, otherwise they'll just fall through. And then you need better logic to exit the loop (like either a label or set a boolean and check that instead of using `while(false)`)

Comment: Thank you, tried now with break, didn’t help. I have to use do while as a part of exercise

Comment: Also, `while(false)` should really be `while(true)`, otherwise you will exit your loop immediately after the first iteration, irrespective of what the rest of the code does. (`while` loops if its condition is true, not false)

Comment: With while(true) got “Execution time out” for each test

Comment: I just noticed that the `do...while` loop basically does nothing. Shouldn't you have the `switch` *inside* the loop? Anyway, if you're having difficulty with this you should probably re-read whatever material you're using to learn java. Because I *know* the next question will be about the loop going on forever *again* because you'll need an exit condition for the loop. Instead, re-study how loops, conditions and `switch` work, reason about what your program is doing and try to re-write it.

Comment: Wouldn’t ask here if it just helped me with re-reading. Tried with continue; with if; with for loop; with return 0/1 and inside either do or while loop. Just can’t get it. Though thanks for suggestions :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Scanner#hasNextInt` to terminate the loop when integers are exhausted.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Language selection");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Customer support");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Check the balance");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Check loan balance");
                break;
            case 0:
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
4 2 17 0
Check loan balance
Customer support
```

Also, note that you need `break` to avoid the cases falling through inadvertently. I did not see any use of `default` in this case and therefore, I have removed it from the demo code.

**Alternatively, using a do-while loop:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;

        do {
            x = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Language selection");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Customer support");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Check the balance");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Check loan balance");
                break;
            }
        } while (x != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s brilliant ! Thank you! It works!  ``` import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextInt()){
       int x=scanner.nextInt();
  switch(x) {
case 1:
      System.out.println("Language selection");
break;
case 2:
       System.out.println("Customer support");
break;
case 3:
       System.out.println("Check the balance");
break;
case 4:
       System.out.println("Check loan balance");
break;
case 0:
System.out.println("Exit");
System.exit(0);
}}}}```